# ajax fails and returns a web page instead of json

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to import a json array from a php script in JavaScript but every time the request fails and the xhr.responseText return the html code of the template of the html template associated to it. I am using xampp.

php code:

```
<?php
// This script is meant to display the data from Insight sensors DB

include('includes/motebymote.html');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){//Use the post method as a request method to the server

    require('mysqli_connect.php');//Give information on which database to use


    if(!empty($_COOKIE["mote_ID"]) || !empty($_COOKIE["std"]) || !empty($_COOKIE["end"])){

        //Setting variables
        $moteID=$_COOKIE["mote_ID"];
        $start=$_COOKIE["std"];
        $end=$_COOKIE["end"];

        if(preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$/", $start) || preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$/", $end)) {

            if(isset($moteID) && isset($start) && isset($end)){

                //Building the query
                $q="SELECT date_time, modality, value FROM sensor_data WHERE mote_id = $moteID and date_time BETWEEN '$start' and '$end'";

                $r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);//Doing the request

                $numRow = mysqli_num_rows($r);


                if ($r && $numRow>0){
                    //echo "<p>There are $numRow data points associated to mote$moteID</p><br>";

                    //echo"<table align ='center' width ='70%' cellpadding='4'><tr><th>Date&Time</th><th> Sensor Type</th><th> Value</th></tr>";

                    $moteArray = array();
                    while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_BOTH)){
                        //echo "<tr align ='center'><td>" .$data['date_time']. "</td><td>" .$data['modality']. "</td><td>" .$data['value']. "</td></tr>";
                        $moteArray[] = $data;                       
                    }
                    //echo"</table>";
                    $JSONMoteArray = json_encode($moteArray);
                    echo $JSONMoteArray;
                }
                else if ($numRow==0){
                    echo "<h1>Sorry there are no data available</h1>
                    <p>There are no data available for mote$moteID</p>";
                }
                else{//Give an error message if the query fails
                    echo '<h1>System Error</h1>
                    <p class="error">We could not record your order due to a system error. We apologize for any inconvenience.</p>'; 
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "<h1> Wrong date format</h1>
            <p>Please input the starting date in a yyyy-mm-dd format</p>";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "<h1> Wrong input</h1>
        <p> Please make sure that the mote is properly selected and that the start and end dates are entered in yyyy-mm-dd format</p>";
    }
    mysqli_close($dbc); //close the database
}

exit(); //exits the script
?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Motes Data</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mote.js" async></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body><br>
        <form action="motebymote.php" method="post">
            <p>Please input a mote number: <input type="text" name="moteNo" id="moteNo"></p>
            <p> Please input a starting date (yyyy-mm-dd):<input type="text" name="stDate" id="stDate"></p>
            <p> Please input an end date (yyyy-mm-dd):<input type="text"  name="endDate" id="endDate"></p>
            <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit"/></p>
            <p><input type="submit" name="display" value="display" id="display"/></p>
            <div id="columnchart_material" style="width: 800px; height: 500px;"></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
var but = document.getElementById("submit");    //Looking for the submit button

if(but){                                            //if the button is clicked activate the event listener
    but.addEventListener("click", moteIDDate);
}

//This function goes to fetch the different values and store them with cookies //to allow motebymote.php to use them
function moteIDDate(){

    var moteID = $('#moteNo').val();
    document.cookie="mote_ID = " + moteID + ";time()+3600";

    var start = $("#stDate").val();
    document.cookie = "std="+start+";time() 3600";

    var end = $("#endDate").val();
    document.cookie= "end="+ end+";time() 3600";
};

var jsonData = $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/Insight/mote2/motebymote.php",
    type:"GET",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(xhr){
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    },
    error: function(xhr){
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: Many questions though, and among those : **1)**  add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on top of your PHP pages (so we know if errors) **2)** why use a template for a PHP response ? (query -> result -> json -> response -> json use -> tpl it, no ?) **3)** Ajax GET to PHP POST ? **4)** *please* get rid of `@`

Comment: Only include your html in the page if you are not posting to the page.... + the answer below.

Comment: I can echo the json array from the php pageso I think the php code is okay but I am kind of new in programming what do you mean by query -> result -> json -> response -> json use -> tpl it, no ? oldPadawan

Comment: I mean : you use Ajax to send a question to PHP, you then get an answer back through Ajax response (say, ie: in json format), then you *decode json* to use a template to properly serve the answer to the browser. Getting the whole page is quite irrelevant IMHO. If PHP answer=ok -> include a page (not the best way, but why not...), but the best seems to be using a `true / false` answer **then** do something

Comment: saying that, via Ajax, you send `mote number + starting date + end date` to PHP -> PHP answers `$moteArray[]` which contains some json encoded data such as `date_time + modality + value` and then you use a template to serve the decoded answer to the browser.

Comment: okay guys I got it thanks

Comment: @AlexAcquier : would seeing a commented & working example help you ?

Comment: Thanks OldPadawan but I manage to get this thing sorted out thanks to all the comments, I do not think that would be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

The php code has "if...== POST"
your javascript ajax call is sending a "GET"

Comment: if I try to introduce the POST it returns the html code plus the json array I want but as string,it also come up in console log of the error function